# I am trying to fletch the user profile from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fletch the user profile from firebase

I am getting these following error:

> The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'docs', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'docs'.

Can anyone help me to get out of these?

[image: i attached the error in picture]

```
  onsearchBtnClick() async {
    isSearching = true;
    setState(() {});
    usersStream = await DatabaseMethods()
        .getUserByDefault(searchUsernameEditingController.text);
    setState(() {});
  }

  Widget searchUsersList() {

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: usersStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
            ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                  return Image.network(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["imgUrl"]);
                },
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
      },
    );
  }
```

Database is:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
// ignore: unused_import
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

class DatabaseMethods {
  Future addUserInfoToDB(
      String userId, Map<String, dynamic> userInfoMap) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(userId)
        .set(userInfoMap);
  }

  Future<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> getUserByUserName(String username) async {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("username", isEqualTo: username)
        .snapshots();
  }

 // getUserByDefault(String text) {}
}
```

I have tried document instead of docs

Comment: It would be helpful if you could attach the usersStream code as well and the Firebase collection & documents structure.

Comment: How is `usersStream` initialized in your code?

Comment: yh added userssSream and data base code. plz help me to solve this

Comment: @VladTM23 i added userStream and database code

Comment: I added userStream code @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: This seems incomplete: `getUserByDefault(String text) {}`

Comment: Sorry that is in comment mode @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Your widget uses `DatabaseMethods().getUserByDefault(searchUsernameEditingController.text);`, but you haven't implemented `getUserByDefault` it seems.